# jUnit testing two boolean arrays

Tags: java, junit

I just noticed that jUnit 4.8.1 does not include support for testing two boolean arrays for equality. There are tons of other assertArrayEquals but none to take in two boolean arrays.

Is there a proper way to do this? My current thinking is that I'd have to iterate over an array and use something like

```
Assert.assertTrue(arrayOne[i] == arrayTwo[i]);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `assertTrue(Arrays.equals(array1, array2));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%5B%5D%29) to compare the two arrays, then assert that they are equivalent.

```
Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
```

`Arrays.equals()` checks the length and each element in the array, so you won't have to worry about iterating over each array.

There is also [`Assert.assertArrayEquals`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(int[],%20int[])), which will give you the exact position that the arrays differed at.

Example:  for a test written as such:

```
@Test
public void doArrayTest() {
    int[] foo = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] bar = {4, 5, 6};
    assertArrayEquals(foo, bar);
}
```

The result would be:

```
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<1> but was:<4>

Expected :1
Actual   :4
```

Comment: The problem with this is that your diagnostics won't tell you what is wrong if the arrays are different, you are going to have to do extra work to find out why they're different

Answer (score 2):

The functionality has been added in JUnit 4.12, which was released in Dec. 2014.

```
assertArrayEquals(boolean[] expecteds, boolean[] actuals)
assertArrayEquals(String message, boolean[] expecteds, boolean[] actuals)
```

For reference: this the the PR that contains the commit:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/632